# How to compare string and bytes correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, string, encoding, byte

I'm trying to read some file as bytes and compare it with "\u0019\u0093\r\n\u001a\n". And I'sure I'll always get byte[]{ 0x19, 0x93, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x1a, 0x0a }.

I tried convert these bytes to string and compared to the string, but always false.

So I try to convert the string to bytes. But also always false when I compare them.

(Using .NET Core 3.0 on Windows 10)

I tried like the following code

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[]{ 0x19, 0x93, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x1a, 0x0a };
string s = "\u0019\u0093\r\n\u001a\n";
System.Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes) == s);
System.Console.WriteLine(s.Length);
foreach (var b in Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s))
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Byte: "+b);
}
System.Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes) == s);
```

the output is:

```
False
6
Byte: 25
Byte: 194
Byte: 147
Byte: 13
Byte: 10
Byte: 26
Byte: 10
False
```

The compare always return false. I found that after the conversion from string to bytes I got one more extra byte and have no idea where had the 194 come from. Why does this happen?

I suppose they should be equal after conversion. Is it wrong?

What should I do if I want to get what I expect?

Comment: In the age of Unicode, there are many ways a Unicode string can be encoded into bytes: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/ | And even within a Unicode string, normalisation will be an issue, as the same Charaacter can be presrented by different Code Points: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.normalize?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: The file appears to be one byte data and not unicode which is two byte data.  So why are you trying to compare a file which is one bytes data with two byte data?  A character is a class with a value that is two bytes and a private property which indicates a character is one or two bytes.  You are setting the private property to two bytes when you use \u0019.

Comment: @jdweng Hi Thanks for your reply. The file I’m trying to read is basically a binary file. These bytes are within the header part and usually invariant. Some bytes actually represent some words, so I just store the correct value as string and try to verify if the file is well formatted by comparing the bytes and the string. So I guess it’s a bad idea and I must compare the bytes value?

Comment: The file has a text header before the actual binary.   If you open an image file with notepad you will see a similar header.  Usually the is a fixed character (a Start character) that separates the header.  Right now I do not know why you are trying to compare with a unicode string when you are not getting unicode.

Comment: You can safely ignore the comment about a file having a "text header". Most text files have no header that would indicate encoding. The only exceptions are things like XML or HTML, which include an ASCII header that states the encoding used, and **optionally** some UTF8 and UTF16 files, which will sometimes start with a sequence of bytes that indicate the encoding (search for "Unicode byte order mark"...note that only for UTF16 does the two-byte sequence indicate byte order; for UTF8 the sequence is three bytes and since UTF8 only has one possible byte order, it's always the same three bytes)

Comment: @jdweng In fact I was reading a book. The sample code is written in Go while I am trying to implement it with C#. There’s a piece of code like ` string(self.ReadBytes(6) != SOME_CONSTANT` where the constant is a string literal “\x19\x93\r\n\x1a\n”. It works fine as expected.

Comment: The literal is one byte character not two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character code at issue, in your original encoded bytes, is `0x0093`.

The problem you are running into is that in the `Default` encoding on your system (which on Windows is going to be whatever the current code page for system is), the character encoded as `0x0093` is unrecognized. So when you attempt to decode it, you get UTF16 character point `0xfffd` (which is the default for the .NET decoders for unrecognized characters). This is then encoded back into your default encoding as `0x93c2` (the sequence of bytes you see in your output, in decimal that is `194` followed by `147`).

For what it's worth, this behavior is consistent with your default encoding being set to UTF8, maybe indicating it's a Linux system (most Windows systems will use some locale-specific code page as the default encoding and not UTF8).

If you want for the original byte `0x93` to translate into a UTF16 character having essentially the same value (i.e. `0x0093`, aka `'\u0093'`), then you need to decode the original bytes using a text encoding where the code point `0x93` does in fact translate to the UTF16 code point `0x0093`.

Fortunately, there's a web site that will in fact tell us for which encodings include this character, and what their value is: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/charsets/containing/U+0093

And from that table, we can see a large number of encodings where this is the case (there are also some encodings where the UTF16 character `'\u0093'` is encoded as a different value, namely `0x33`…obviously, we don't want any of these). The first encoding in the list — "ISO-8859-1" — appears suitable, so let's try using that to decode your bytes:

```cs
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 0x19, 0x93, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x1a, 0x0a };
string s = "\u0019\u0093\r\n\u001a\n";
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
System.Console.WriteLine(encoding.GetString(bytes) == s);
System.Console.WriteLine(s.Length);
foreach (var b in encoding.GetBytes(s))
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Byte: " + b);
}
System.Console.WriteLine(encoding.GetString(bytes) == s);
```

This outputs just what you want:

```
True
6
Byte: 25
Byte: 147
Byte: 13
Byte: 10
Byte: 26
Byte: 10
True
```

And the bytes displayed are even the exact bytes in your `bytes` array, which we can demonstrate by adding this line to the end of your program:

```
System.Console.WriteLine(encoding.GetBytes(s).SequenceEqual(bytes));
```

That will also print `True`.

And the moral of the story is: knowing the original encoding of the bytes you're trying to decode **is not optional**. You must know exactly which encoding was used, because it's just that: an *encoding*. You might as well be trying to decode encrypted data, if you are using the wrong encoding.

Different text encodings are, by definition, different. That means that the bytes in one encoding mean something completely different than they do in some other encoding (sort of…most encodings overlap in the lowest 128 code points, because they are all based on ASCII). You'll just get random results if you use the wrong encoding to decode some bytes (or, as in this case, the decoder will simply not recognize the character and translate it into a placeholder that represents an unrecognized character).